# error TS2322: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'. [(ngModel)]="todoItem" (keyup) ="addTodo()"

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I'm trying to bind my input to be able to display string. But I've this error:

Error:
list.component.html:3:15 - error TS2322: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'.
.

3  [(ngModel)]="todoItem"
~~~~~~~~~
4  (keyup) ="addTodo()"

```
src/app/components/todo-list/todo-list.component.ts:5:16
  5   templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',




todo-list.componentn.html :


    <input type="text"
   placeholder="What needs to be done" 
   [(ngModel)]="todoItem"
   />
  
      <div class="item-left"  *ngFor="let todo of todos">
          <input type='checkbox' >
          <p>{{todo.title}}</p>
      </div>

todo-list.component.ts:

  
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  
  @Component({
    selector: 'app-todo-list',
    templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./todo-list.component.css'],
  })
  export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
    todos!: Todos[];
    todoItem!: string;
    constructor() {}
  
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.todoItem = '';
      this.todos = [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Surya',
        },
      ];
    }
 
  }

//interface to help with type error

  interface Todos {
    id: number;
    title: string;
  }
```

Comment: Where is `(keyup) ="addTodo()"` in your code. you have shared required code here.

Comment: Hi, I finally solved it.  It was a silly mistake in @Input()... . I was binding the wrong data in todo-list.componentn.html. Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it.

Comment: This error can also be caused by not importing the module that's attempting to use `ngModel` into appModule. Say you have  `secondModule`, and `thirdModule` and you import only `secondModule` into `appModule` and you import `thirdModule` into `secondModule` and then `thirdModule` trys to use `ngModel`, you'll get this error until you import `thirdModule` into `appModule`.

Comment: @user14432224, would you be able to show us how you fixed it? please

Answer (score 118):

May be import the FormsModule in app.module.ts can solve this problem.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
...
imports: [
..,
FormsModule
],
```

Save and ng serve the project.

Comment: fixed issue: "Event is not assignable to string" in angular15, thanks buddy!

Answer (score 33):

**ngModel** is defined in the Forms module and by default, it is not imported, so if you want to build any kind of form or wanna use **ngModel** you need to explicitly import it.

In **app.Module.ts** you need to do this.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
      imports: [
         FormsModule
      ]
```

Answer (score 11):

I also faced this issue. I have already imported FormsModule in app.module. Even after that, I got the error "can't bind ngModel, it is not a known property of input". I was confused and spent lot of time in this. Luckily, I found I haven't imported the component in my app.module. I used CLI only to generate the component. But I am not sure why it has not added to App Module. Usually, it does.

So, if you face this issue, it is worth to check once in app.module whether the component has been added into the declaration array.

Adding in declaration array, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 10):

I am using custom modules. So for me I added:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { MyComponent } from './mycomponent.component'
import { SomeOtherComponent } from './components/someother.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
    SomeOtherComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RealtorToolsRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class MyModule{ }
```

I added the Forms module in the parent Module, and the child components inherited the FormsModule.

This is an alternative to adding FormsModule to the app.module.ts

Answer (score 5):

You need to add FormsModule to the import field in your app.module.ts

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'`
`imports: [FormsModule],`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was **ReactiveFormsModule** that was missing in my module:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

...

  imports: [
     ...
     ReactiveFormsModule,
     ...
  ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Include ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts.

`import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';`

`imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, AppRoutingModule],`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the error. Those who are suggesting import from `FormsModule` are correct but there are other reason for this error.

My case was, I imported a component in `something-routing.module.ts` but didn't import it previously in `something.module.ts` and also didn't mention the component in `something.module.ts` declaration array. Do this two things and it should be resolved.

Comment: Those who are using Angular 16+. and have created your component as standalone then you must import FormsModule in the import Array.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add `FormsModule` in any other sub module different from the app module, especially when you're using the ngModel in a component of that sub module. Put it in the import array of the module

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this error I faced is not exactly the same cause of theerror in the question. But since it is the same error report I think it would be helpful to share.

I also faced this issue, while working with angular 12. I have already imported FormsModule in app.module. Even after that, I got the error "Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'string'.". I was confused. Luckily, I found that is was a simple typo, turned out that the error message was not very helpful at that point; I had used
`[(NgModel)]` instead of `[(ngModel)]`
By simply correcting this typo the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom-routing.module to app.mobule, but do not add custom.module to app.module

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same issue even after importing FormsModule in the app.component.ts as below:**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, Container, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular_Basics';
}
```

**So, I had to add the FormsModule even in the SearchComponent as I used the ngModel in this component as below:**

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule, NavComponent, HeaderComponent,NotificationComponent,FormsModule],
    templateUrl: './container.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./container.component.css']
})

export class Container{
    
}
```

- With the latest version of Angular, we do not have app.module file, hence I have not used that file to import the FormsModule.

Comment: yes that's right. As Angular has introduced standalone we need to to import it in *.module.ts file.. Instead do it in the component's import array.

Answer (score 0):

check the component module exist in app.module.ts file

Comment: This is not really a useful answer. Can you explain what's wrong and why your solution solves that problem?

Answer (score 0):

While most of the times it really is a missing `FormsModule` import,
I had a case where `public-api.ts` was missing the library's module export.

Adding

```
export * from './lib/my-library.module';
```

to `public-api.ts` fixed this error for that particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported FormsModule and it is still not working look at the router:

```
loadChildren: () => ...
```

And watch out that you don't accidentaly put `lazy-routing.module.ts` instead of `lazy.module.ts`.

`lazy-routing.module.ts` still works but not if you try to use imports.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and fixed it by fixing a wrong import totally unrelated.

Saying just in case somebody has the same kind of issue... The error was definitely unclear.

*(I had a lot of errors to fix on my project, like 3K+ so I started stupidly from the bottom besides I should have started from the top)*

Answer (score 0):

I have two Modules: `app.module` and `admin.module`:

The component that had the issue resides in the `admin.module`:

**Admin/SomeComponent html:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="someField" />
<br />
<span>current value: {{someField}}</span>
```

**Admin/SomeComponent ts:**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    someField: string = "";
    constructor() { }
}
```

The other answers is correct in that you have to import the `FormsModule` in `admin.module`:

**Admin Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SomeComponent } from './some/some.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule // <-- Import for [(ngModel)] to work in SomeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
    ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

But that alone did not seem to do anything to solve my issue, also import the `AdminModule` in `AppModule` for it to work:

**App Module:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AdminModule // <-- Import sub Admin module
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Seems like not importing the `AdminModule` into `AppModule`, when building/serving the project, it doesn't compile the necessary imports in `AdminModule` for `SomeComponent` to use.

So make sure to import any sub modules in the `AppModule` as well.